# ExpandableListView item view

Tags: android, list, expandablelistview

Is the possible to set item view height to all free space on screen with collapsed row' headers? Now I've had a constant height and in a big screens I've got a free space on the bottom of the screen

Comment: show us your layout and screenshot.

Comment: @RahulTiwari I found https://github.com/mpalka/RoboAccordionView lib to make exactly what i need, but is the real to do it with ExpandableListView?

Comment: if that's what you need grab it :)